# What are the out-of-the-box grants for AccountAdmin and SysAdmin in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I had a brand new Snowflake account and ran the following:

```
show grants to role sysadmin;
show grants to role accountadmin;
```

What grants would each have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking for someone to officially refute what I have below. Until that happens, I'm going to guess that any grant on ACCOUNTADMIN or SYSADMIN that doesn't have a "granted_by" field was set up or controlled by Snowflake itself.

```
show grants to role accountadmin;
select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) t
where "granted_by" = '';
```

I think this makes logical sense, and it's also consistent w/ how SECURITYADMIN is set up. I know I haven't changed any grants on SecurityAdmin, and the three grants that it currently has are the default ones and have blanks for 'granted_by'

Here is the output:

```
created_on                    privilege            granted_on      name                                                             grant_option
2019-12-17 18:20:34.000 -0800 CREATE ACCOUNT       ACCOUNT         YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME                                                true  
2019-12-17 18:20:34.000 -0800 CREATE SHARE         ACCOUNT         YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME                                                true  
2019-12-17 18:20:34.000 -0800 EXECUTE MANAGED TASK ACCOUNT         YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME                                                true  
2019-12-17 18:20:34.000 -0800 EXECUTE TASK         ACCOUNT         YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME                                                true  
2019-12-17 18:20:34.000 -0800 IMPORT SHARE         ACCOUNT         YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME                                                true  
2019-12-17 18:20:34.000 -0800 MONITOR EXECUTION    ACCOUNT         YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME                                                true  
2019-12-17 18:20:34.000 -0800 MONITOR SECURITY     ACCOUNT         YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME                                                true  
2019-12-17 18:20:34.000 -0800 MONITOR USAGE        ACCOUNT         YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME                                                true  
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 REFERENCE_USAGE      DATABASE        ORGANIZATION_USAGE                                               false 
2019-03-15 09:27:08.000 -0700 USAGE                ROLE            SECURITYADMIN                                                    true  
2019-03-15 09:27:08.000 -0700 USAGE                ROLE            SYSADMIN                                                         true  
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 USAGE                SCHEMA          SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE                                          false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 USAGE                SCHEMA          SNOWFLAKE.ORGANIZATION_USAGE                                     false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 USAGE                SCHEMA          SNOWFLAKE.READER_ACCOUNT_USAGE                                   false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.AUTOMATIC_CLUSTERING_HISTORY             false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.COLUMNS                                  false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.COPY_HISTORY                             false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.DATABASES                                false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.DATABASE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY           false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.DATA_TRANSFER_HISTORY                    false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.FILE_FORMATS                             false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.FUNCTIONS                                false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES                          false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_USERS                          false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.LOAD_HISTORY                             false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.LOGIN_HISTORY                            false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.MATERIALIZED_VIEW_REFRESH_HISTORY        false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.METERING_DAILY_HISTORY                   false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.METERING_HISTORY                         false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.PIPES                                    false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.PIPE_USAGE_HISTORY                       false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY                            false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS                  false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.REPLICATION_USAGE_HISTORY                false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.ROLES                                    false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.SCHEMATA                                 false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.SEQUENCES                                false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.STAGES                                   false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.STAGE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY              false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.STORAGE_USAGE                            false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES                                   false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS                        false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS                    false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.USERS                                    false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.VIEWS                                    false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.WAREHOUSE_LOAD_HISTORY                   false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY               false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ORGANIZATION_USAGE.PREVIEW_DATA_TRANSFER_DAILY_HISTORY false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ORGANIZATION_USAGE.PREVIEW_METERING_DAILY_HISTORY      false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.ORGANIZATION_USAGE.PREVIEW_STORAGE_DAILY_HISTORY       false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.READER_ACCOUNT_USAGE.LOGIN_HISTORY                     false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.READER_ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY                     false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.READER_ACCOUNT_USAGE.RESOURCE_MONITORS                 false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.READER_ACCOUNT_USAGE.STORAGE_USAGE                     false 
2019-03-15 09:27:10.000 -0700 SELECT               VIEW            SNOWFLAKE.READER_ACCOUNT_USAGE.WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY        false
```

For SYSADMIN, I'll do the same, and assume the same:

```
show grants to role sysadmin;
select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) t
where "granted_by" = '';

2019-03-15 09:27:08.000 -0700 CREATE DATABASE  ACCOUNT YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME ROLE SYSADMIN true 
2019-03-15 09:27:08.000 -0700 CREATE WAREHOUSE ACCOUNT YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME ROLE SYSADMIN true
```

Answer (score 1):

The ACCOUNTADMIN role has the following grants per se; on these various ref article pages, you can see what the role allows the user to do (and how to grant other roles the ability as well):

- [View account level Credit and Storage usage](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/admin-monitoring-usage.html)
- [View account usage views](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage.html)
- [Configure virtual warehouse resource monitors](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/resource-monitors.html)
- [Configure account parameters](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/admin-account-management.html)
- [Configure network policies](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/network-policies.html)
- [Manage Provider Data Shares](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-sharing-gs.html)
- [Manage Reader accounts](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-create.html)
- [Manage Consumer Data Shares](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-share-consumers.html)

Here's a great reference page w/ all the privileges.  To recap what Seeling mentioned, SECURITYADMIN has implicit grants for User and Role management, and SYSADMIN has grants for Warehouse and Database object management.

- [Access Control Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html)

Comment: What do you mean "you can't see them via show grants"? When I run "show grants to role accountadmin;" I see the grants.

Comment: Thanks Erick. I'm less interested in what each role can *do* ... and more interested in exactly which privileges they have. I think my answer answers it, but I'm looking for someone to hopefully disprove it.

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake documentation on system roles provides some high level recommendation on privileges recommended for the system built-in roles:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html#system-defined-roles

Some details for AccountAdmin:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-considerations.html#using-the-accountadmin-role

which implies that for SECURITYADMIN role:

> > The security administrator (SECURITYADMIN) role includes the privileges to create and manage users and roles

and for SYSADMIN role:

> > The system administrator (SYSADMIN) role includes the privileges to create warehouses, databases, and all database objects (schemas, tables, etc.).

Comment: thank you for your post. I'm actually looking for the specific grants that are available.